# Removing a Program from Windows 7's Start Menu forever?

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

I'm gonna remove YM! icon from Windows 7's Start Menu for good, I mean I wanna remove it even I use it.

I've been using `Right Click >> Remove From This List` but It comes back after using once!
How can I remove the program from above list forever?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows 7 maintains a list of recently used applications. As soon as you begin to use other programs more often, it will no longer appear in the list.

To remove it forever, simply locate the Start Menu entry and remove it from the list. (You can easily reach your user-specific list by right-clicking on "All programs" and choosing "Open", or "Open All Users" for the system-wide Start Menu.

As far as I know, you cannot specifically exclude one application. You can, however, disable displaying recently used programs on the Start Menu. To do this:

1. Click *Start*
2. Right-click on *All Programs* and select *Properties*
3. Under the tab *Start Menu*, uncheck the first option in *Privacy* (and optionally the second option as well)

Comment: Thanks Paul. But I wanted to access it with Start Menu, I just wanted to remove from the `recently used`. Is it possible ?

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot specifically exclude one application. You can, however, disable displaying recently used programs on the Start Menu. To do this, consult the "Taskbar and Start Menu Properties" and under the tab "Start Menu", uncheck the first option in "Privacy".

Comment: A quick look on Google revealed this possible resolution, though I haven't tried it: http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/21866-exclude-programs-start-menu-list.html#post235515

Answer (score 3):

I have had the same problem several months ago. I didn't find a solution (which however doesn't mean it doesn't exits), so I have simply deleted the program from Start Menu, like Paul suggested and pinned it to taskbar.