# How to make a specific program not show up on start menu

Tags: windows-7, windows, privacy, start-menu

I would like certain programs to never show up on the Windows 7 start menu. I can remove them from the start menu just fine, but then when I run them, they show up again. If I right click the windows button in the lower left corner, and then hit properties, I can uncheck "Store and display recently opened programs in the Start menu". This works, but then only programs that I specifically add to the start menu will be there. How can I make the start window show all programs normally, except for the specific ones that I don't want on there?

Comment: Might I ask why you don't want it doing that?

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/121520/removing-a-program-from-windows-7s-start-menu-forever and registry edit link to make it happen if you so choose : http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/21866-exclude-programs-start-menu-list.html#post235515

Comment: Cool, thanks @Panhandel! I would select that as the answer, but you can't really do that with comments, so...

Answer (score 0):

That jump list is generated by a most-recently-used list that Windows tracks.  You can't exclude a particular shortcut from being tracked in this way.

But, if you right-click on the app and hit `Run as Administrator` or `Run as Different User`, Windows does not track those and you can keep it from showing up on the jump list -- as long as you make a habit of always running it that way.